# Video editing in AIR - make an instant video preview

Tags: actionscript-3, video, air, editing

I'm making video editing software in AIR.  To make an instant preview, I need a way to display various tracks straight away.  The problem is FLVs don't synchronise well when tracking - so you can't use FLVs in this type of preview.  Plus I want a green screen option to the preview, which normally requires some processing time.

A similar editor is built with AIR, and has this ability.  So it must be possible without having to run external software like ffmpeg - which is time consuming.

My question is - how is this done?  Is it possible to use AIR to view a different video format synchronised easily?  Or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer - but let me know if anyone has comments.

It's possible to set up ffmpeg as a streaming server.  I should be able to get my AIR software to access the stream on localhost, and use this to create an instant preview video in the video editor.